# Event Handler onComplete controller is not going to task.isSuccessful()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, task

In the below code, it is entering onComplete but is not entering if(task.isSuccessful()). Is there any way to know where it is failing, and how can I fix this?

```
private void register (final String username, String fullname, String email, String password){
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: I think you may be struggling with the fact that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is asynchronous. If you want to see the result, put a breakpoint on the `if (task.isSuccessful()){` line and let it run in the debugger. Once the breakpoint hits, you can inspect the result of the task (or its exception).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I used a debugger and it isn't going into the if statement. Also, what do you mean when you say createUserWithEmailAndPassword is asynchronous? Sorry, I am new to coding in Android Studio. Thanks

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks, but I am currently using it. Do you happen to know why I am getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the end tag from to /> in the manifest file. That fixed it.